# Clicking Button on Top of Text Won't Go to URL

Tags: html, css, url, button

So, my button, for some reason, won't go to the URL that is defined *when the user clicks directly on the text lying on top of the button*. (ie: for my button, "Test Text")

When you click on the button, it always depresses, but it only goes to the linked URL when you click outside of the text's area.

I have tried using a `<div>` instead of `<a>`, but no luck with that either.

You can see the button live at `http://198.154.213.30/~foster2/index.php/news`

Below is the code for my button:

```
<a class="button3D" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Test Text</a>

<style>
.button3D {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    background: #650404;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid #4e0202;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -5px #222;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -5px #222;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -5px #222;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button3D:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -9px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 178px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 11px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #650404;
    border-top: 0;
}
.button3D:after {
    content: "";
    color: #c56338;
    line-height: 180px;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    left: 1px;
    width: 178px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #891414;
    border-top: 0;
}


.button3D:active {
    width: 158px;
    height: 41px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -33px;
    margin-left: -79px;
    line-height: 36px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #eee;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid #3c0101;
    background: #4e0202;
    border-top: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
}
.button3D:active:before {
    top: 0;
    height: 42px;
    width: 158px;
    left: -12px;
    padding: 0 1px;
    border: 11px solid #b3b294;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #deddad;
    border-top: 0;
}
.button3D:active:after {
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 182px;
    left: -13px;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 25px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 25px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 25px -15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset;
}
</style>
```

Appreciate any input/insight you can provide for me as to how I can fix this problem.

Comment: By removing all the properties of the pseudo-elements, the link then works. Maybe the problem lives somewhere in there... Im' not sure if you can add another pseudo-element to a previous one like you have here -> .button3D:active::before. Also could try changing the css to a.button3D. Just some thoughts...

Comment: Appreciate your feedback, but I wasn't successful with those suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the link is moving. When you click and hold a link you can drag off the link and it will not navigate. It appears that the moving link is triggering this functionality. The only thing I can think that you could do is use JavaScript onmousedown to navigate.